# Erratic recursion in C

Tags: c, recursion, undefined-behavior

I ran this code on C and in Java and I got 65 and 55 respectively. I cannot fathom how C can get 65. Please help.

```
int recur(int count) 
{
    if(count==10)
        return count;
    else
        return (count+recur(++count));
}

void main()
{
    printf("%d\n",recur(0));
}
```

Comment: Change `++count` to `count + 1`. The preincrement is incrementing `count` before both usages of it on that line.

Comment: Oh, no wonder. Thanks! I was trying to understand recursion and had copied this code from another question on SOF which used increment operators.

Comment: well then edit your question...

Answer (score 1):

```
return (count+recur(++count));
```

Is [Undefined Behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).
On different compilers you may have different results, even same compiler with different compilation options may result to different output.

Comment: This still doesn't help the OP _fix_ the problem.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: As Paulpro said in a comment to the question, if I changed the (++count) to (count+1), the code will run correctly.

Comment: It should still be part of the answer. An answer is supposed to be complete. Comments aren't gaurenteed to stay forever.

Comment: Yeah, if he had written a more complete explanation, I would've accepted the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Rewriting the code  and testing on [codepad](http://codepad.org/QNDovkWN) with some debug statements shows what's happening. I encourage you to take this approach with running code to see what's happening.

```
int recur(int count) 
{
    int ret;
    if(count==10)
       ret = count;
    else {
       printf("Count Before = %d\n", count);
       ret =  (count +recur(++count));
    }
    printf("Count after = %d\n", ret);
    return ret; 
}

 void main()
 {
    printf("%d\n",recur(0));
 }
```

Running it gives this

```
Count Before = 0
Count Before = 1
Count Before = 2
Count Before = 3
Count Before = 4
Count Before = 5
Count Before = 6
Count Before = 7
Count Before = 8
Count Before = 9
Count after = 10
Count after = 20
Count after = 29
Count after = 37
Count after = 44
Count after = 50
Count after = 55
Count after = 59
Count after = 62
Count after = 64
Count after = 65
65
```

So you can see that recurse up to 10 first , **then add 10,** then 9 then 8 etc...

Changing it to i = (count + recur(count + 1))

gives

```
Count Before = 0
Count Before = 1
Count Before = 2
Count Before = 3
Count Before = 4
Count Before = 5
Count Before = 6
Count Before = 7
Count Before = 8
Count Before = 9
Count after = 10
Count after = 19
Count after = 27
Count after = 34
Count after = 40
Count after = 45
Count after = 49
Count after = 52
Count after = 54
Count after = 55
Count after = 55
55
```

But now the 10 level of nesting is only reached but added amount is still at 9.

Ie. the pre increment means you're adding an extra 10.

Comment: What this does is the following:

recur(0) = 1 + recur(1) = 1 + 2 + recur(2) = 1 + 2 + 3 + recur(3)
.....
= 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+recur(10)
= 65


The problem lies in the fact that the pre-increment operator is the first to be executed in a statement, so it changes the recurring return statement to:
return ((count+1) + (recur(count+1)));

This causes an ambiguity as the return statement adds (argument+1) twice instead of (argument+(argument+1).

The code should remove the increment operator and change it to (count+1).